# Using jQuery's this object in a function

Tags: jquery, html, dom

How come the following does not work (attribute values are all 'undefined')

```
$(".item").wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr("data-pid") + '.html"></a>');
```

but this code does?

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr("data-pid") + '.html"></a>');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `this` is defined by the parent function, in your case `this` would be global window or whatever you have. If you create a function `this` will be defined as the element you are targeting.

Comment: It is a scoping thing. I'm not really sure what the this in '<a href="' + $(this).attr("data-pid") + '.html"></a>' would be referring to without more context.  The this in the second example refers to the .item because of the anonymous function it was called from more or less belonging to the .item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because calling `$(this)` when looking up a class means you are effectively looking at a collection of objects not the individual object which has the `attr` property (the collection doesn't have an `attr` property as it wouldn't make sense for it to have one).

Iterating over the collection with `$.each` means you can access each element and access its `attr` property.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.item').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr("data-pid") + '.html"></a>');
});
```

[`this`](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/) refer to the current element in the each function block

---

Better Version of your code

```
$('.item').wrap(function () {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).data("pid") + '.html"></a>';
});
```

---

```
$(".item").wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr("data-pid") + '.html"></a>');
```

here `this` is `window` object  which doesn't have `attr("data-pid")` so it return `undefined`

Comment: The OP seems to know that, as the code you posted is exactly what he posted saying that it works. He wants to know why the first example doesn't work.

Comment: @j08691 was just updating sir. Updated now

Comment: Does the callback function in `wrap()` automatically iterate through the collection, i.e. all elements? If yes then why is it better than `each()`?

Comment: @ScepticalJule yes it does you can try it :)

Comment: I just did and it works like charms but I needed to understand what I write.

Answer (score 0):

The dot in `$('.whatever')` indicates a selector of class names, which doesn't guarantee you finding a unique element. This means you could potential be selecting a collection instead which you'd need to iterate over or do a `.each()` over.

If you have an ID to use instead, you could try this:

```
$('#whatever')
```

Which is a selector based on ID instead. As long as you're safe with your ID's (only one element has that ID name), it should be safe.